# Alternatives to missing SSAT and USAT instructions in Arm64?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

We are in the process of porting a major application from Arm32 to Arm64. Our algorithms make frequent use of the `SSAT` and `USAT` instructions. They perform a left or right shift of any size then a signed or unsigned saturate to an arbitrary number of bits. This is extremely useful for image processing algorithms, because we can perform some math that generates a 32-bit integer result, then grab whatever bits we need out of that (saturated to the max/min of the bit depth of the output image) with a single instruction.

These instructions have inexplicably disappeared in Arm64 and the closest alternative we've found are `SQSHRN` / `UQSHRN` / `SQSHLN` / `UQSHLN` which perform a shift and saturate but are far more limited in the saturation they perform (`USAT` could saturate to any width, even 7 bits; the new instructions can only saturate to half the width of the input, e.g. 16 bits in case of a 32 bit input, which would require additional processing to achieve the needed result).

Can someone explain why these instructions were dropped, and what's the best way to efficiently port existing code that uses them?

Comment: Write their equivalent in C and let the compiler translate that code?

Comment: @IraBaxter writing saturation code in C requires a branch ("if value is over 255 then set it to 255"), which is something I'd rather avoid deep within an algorithm kernel.

Comment: See my answer for clamping to 255: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6504/8792

Comment: @itaych - why can't you(r compiler) use conditional instructions instead of branching?

Comment: @TobySpeight because arm64 doesn't have a whole lot of those. Do you have a particular solution in mind?

Comment: @Jester - no I don't.  I'm more familiar with ARM32, where most/all instructions can be conditional.  I just assumed that AArch64 would work similarly.

Comment: @IraBaxter that's the reason why S/USAT is so useful, just one instruction clamps and flags.

Comment: Regarding the question, arm64 is not so focused on DSP tasks as arm32 (with cortex Ms or Rs), so it makes sense that a lot of DSP instructions were dropped from arm32 to arm64.

Comment: Well, you could try shift-left your desired distance in a big register, compare that to 255,  clear a register/subtract the carry and then or this into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### SIMD solution

Let's do the signed version first.

First of all, ARM64 has a non-narrowing version of the saturated-shift that saturates at the full word size: `sqshl`.  You can saturate at a different bit count by left-shifting so that the desired top bit becomes the top bit of the word; the shift count can also be offset to incorporate your desired initial left-shift.   Then right-shift to get back.

So for instance, the equivalent of `ssat r0, #14, r1, lsl #3` could be achieved by

```
sqshl   v0.4s, v1.4s, #(32 - 14 + 3)
sshr    v0.4s, v0.4s, #(32 - 14)
```

It's two instructions instead of one, but on the flip side you do get four results at a time.  On a Cortex A-72, this sequence should have a latency of 7 cycles and throughput of one per 2 cycles.  (For contrast, on the same chip in ARM32 mode, a single `ssat` has latency 2 cycles and throughput one per cycle, so if my math is right, four of them is latency 5 cycles and throughput of one per 4 cycles)

In C with intrinsics, we'd have

```
int32x4_t ssat4(int32x4_t x) {
    return vshrq_n_s32(vqshlq_n_s32(x, (32 - SATBITS + SHIFT)), 32 - SATBITS);
}
```

These instructions are available in the usual 8x16, 16x8, 32x4, 64x2 versions, according to the size of your input.  They can also take their shift counts in a register instead of an immediate, in case your shift and saturation are not compile-time constants (at extra cost: latency 9 cycles, throughout 1 per 4 cycles).  ARM32 `ssat` can't do that at all.

For the equivalent of `usat`, use `sqshlu` instead, and a logical right-shift `ushr`.  This replicates the somewhat odd behavior that despite the "unsigned" name, `usat` actually saturates a *signed* value into the range `0..INT_MAX`, with all negative inputs mapped to 0.  If you want true unsigned saturation (`0..UINT_MAX`) use `uqshl`.  (Though actually in this case, `shl / umin` is probably faster.)

To saturate to other arbitrary ranges, not necessarily powers of 2, you have `smax/smin` and `umax/umin`.  But then the shift would be separate.

Answer (score 1):

--UPDATE-- times on correct test were significantly slower when using non assembly code, i'll keep looking for different method

i compared this assembly code:

```
#define __arm_ssat(src, bits)   asm("ssat %[srcr], %[satv], %[srcr]"    :[srcr]"+r"(src):[satv]"I"(bits));
```

with this:

```
#define MAX_SIGNED_NUM(bits) ((1 << (bits -1)) -1)
#define __arm_ssat(src, bits)   {src = ((src > MAX_SIGNED_NUM(bits)) ? MAX_SIGNED_NUM(bits) : src);}
```

when running this --UPDATED TEST-- on 32bit device:

```
volatile  void assert_ssat_asm(int* buf, size_t loops){
    int64_t num = buf[0];
    int64_t num_a = buf[1];
    int64_t num_b = buf[2];
    int sum = 0;
    struct timeval tmv1; gettimeofday(&tmv1,NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i){
        __arm_ssat(num, 8);
        sum+=num;
        assert( 127 == num);
        num = buf[0];

        __arm_ssat(num, 16);
        sum+=num;
        assert(32767 == num);

        __arm_ssat(num_a, 8);
        sum+=num;
        assert( 127 == num_a);
        num_a = buf[1];

        __arm_ssat(num_a, 16);
        sum+=num;
        assert( 690 == num_a);

        __arm_ssat(num_b, 8);
        sum+=num;
        assert( 127 == num_b);
        num_b = buf[2];

        __arm_ssat(num_b, 16);
        sum+=num;
        assert( 32767 == num_b);
    }
    struct timeval tmv2; gettimeofday(&tmv2,NULL);
    int tdiff_usec = (tmv2.tv_sec*1000000 + tmv2.tv_usec) - (tmv1.tv_sec*1000000 + tmv1.tv_usec);

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    printf("ran %d times, total time: %d,  average time asm: %.7f\n", loops, tdiff_usec, (double)tdiff_usec/loops);
}
int main ()
{
    int buf[] = { 69000, 690, 64000 };
    test_ssat(buf, 1000000);
}
```

I've got those results:

> run 1000000 loops, average time reg: 0.0210270
>
> run 1000000 loops, average time assembly: 0.0057960

Comment: Your  0.0 average time probably just shows that everything optimized away (like it should) with pure C, because you aren't using the results.

Comment: @PeterCordes thought about it, so i've added: volatile int64_t rr; and rr = num; after every __arm_ssat. still the same results.

Comment: Do more loops to have a longer times, might be more precise.